# How to Find Shortest Path Back to Self in a Graph/Adjacency Matrix - NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I've got a problem where I need to find a connected loop within an adjacency matrix. I'd like to find a loop that connects back to the original node over `x` hops. `shortest_path` algorithms provided by NetworkX do not provide an option for a node to be the same `source` and `target`.

For an example, this is the graph, and I'd like to find `three` colors with the largest distance between each other:

[image]

This might be represented similar to:

[image: erdos-renyi graph]

**SOLUTIONS THAT DIDN'T WORK**

[Modification of shortest path algorithm (route from a node to itself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954743/modification-of-shortest-path-algorithm-route-from-a-node-to-itself)

There is a post here that mentions potentially setting `weights` or `distances` to infinite along the diagonal, but it doesn't appear `networkx.all_shortest_paths`, and any of the pathing algoirthms respect the `self-loops` as seen below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could figure out how to do this was using `simple_cycles` and then iterating through all cycles/loops to figure out what the distance might be:

```
cycles = [p for p in nx.simple_cycles(G)]

num_nodes = 3
for nodes in cycles: 
  if (len(nodes) != num_nodes): 
    continue
  print(nodes)
  total = 0
  node_pairs = list(walk_list(nodes,2,1))

  for pair in node_pairs: 
    if len(pair) == 2: 
      total += G[pair[0]][pair[1]]['weight']
    else: 
      total+= G[pair[0]][nodes[0]]['weight']


  print(f"Total Distance: {total}")
```

Does someone have a better solution?